# Mapping with Tikz and Gnuplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

i created a plot with Tikz and Gnuplot showing some z Values over x,y Values. I also created an outline which defines my geometry for the specimen. Now i want to delete or not show the data which is outside the outline. I just tried to fill the outer area with white colour but the 3D Surface plot is always in front. Any answers to this issue?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{filecontents*}{Test.dat}
#1 2 3
-0.346 0.28 207
-0.306 0.28 203
-0.266 0.28 210
-0.226 0.28 214
-0.226 0.20 244
-0.186 0.20 255
-0.266 0.12 248
-0.226 0.08 261
-0.186 0.08 246
0 0 320
0 0.3 260
-0.4 0.3 220
-0.4 0 240 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{Outline.dat}
#1 2 
-0.39 0.05
-0.05 0.05
-0.050 0.28
-0.39 0.28
-0.39 0.05
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document} 


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar,
xmin=-0.4,
xmax=0.05,
ymin=-0.05,
ymax=0.35,
view={0}{90},
]

\addplot3 [surf] gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {
set dgrid3d 40,40 spline;
splot 'Test.dat';       
};
\addplot [no markers, very thick, name path=A] table []{Outline.dat};

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can certainly put a white path in front (or use a filter). However, nobody here can run your example. Apart from the fact that your document does not start with `\documentclass` and does not end with `\end{document}`, we do not have your data file nor the contour you want to use. Just inventing these to answer this in principle interesting question is too much effort, at least for me.

Comment: Okay sorry! Hope its better now!